# What software do you use for drawing diagrams?

Tags: user-research, software, diagramming, diagram

what type of software do you use for drawing diagrams (user flows) in a faster manner? I tried draw.io as an online tool because I wanted defined shapes in order to make the flow faster. I do not want to use Sketch, Illustrator, Photoshop type of thing because I have to create my own shapes which is time consuming, projects are different from one another.

Comment: Software recommendations are not on-topic for this site. I have linked to an older question (also closed) that may give you some direction, but such questions are no longer suitable for Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest one I have in mind is powerpoint. I tend to make a lot of process modelling demonstration through it.

We could also use Bizagi, which is way more professional or even Axure with icon package.

Depends on what you're going for.